# #include <stdio.h> Intellisense, Noob Error

Tags: c, include, stdio

Beginner Noob Question,
Why doesn't my VSC recognize #include <stdio.h> in C programming? I have Microsoft C/C++ extension downloaded and everything.I created a new directory and folder and started to write the code but got the error on #include.
I tried reinstalling VSC.
I am starting my degree from square one this fall term in CET. Wanted to get a head start and brush up on C again.
I cant even printf because for some reason #include <stdio.h> isn't recognized.
It gives me intellisense errors and red underlines #include <stdio.h>
What do I do to start programming in C and have the code compile and execute appropriately in VSC?
Do I need to specify the C>Cpp Default Intellisense Mode or edit compiler path?
Do I need to specify direct path in json settings or edit something in the configuration settings??
I saw some video saying I must download mingw64? Is that a compiler? Why would VSC and the C/C++ extension not include all that you need? Why doesn't it just download mingw64 by default if it is needed to write in C on VSC.
I did review similar questions but feel a newer thread needs to be created so other noobs like me can git gud quicker. I know this shouldn't stump me so,
Sorry for the beginner question. I am a beginner and finally downloaded VSC, before I used an easy in-browser cloud based VSC.
I am asking for a solution but, also more so to understand the why/what is going on. Other posts lack the explanation and just provide possible yet vague one sentence solutions.

Need #include <stdio.h> to not have error so I can compile and run simple code. Just trying to warm up with some printf's and if else statements and what have you.

Comment: If it's only an IntelliSense error, then you need to configure `c_cpp_properties.json`. If it's a build error then you need to configure `tasks.json`. Assuming Windows and MingW, please read [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). There are links to other OS/compiler combinations.

Comment: Also note that Visual Studio Code have a reputation of not being beginner-friendly. With that said, I (and many others) learned programming on editors *much* worse than that, so don't give up. Unlike us, you do have easy access to *very* good documentation.

Comment: "Why would VSC and the C/C++ extension not include all that you need?" Because they have no clue what compiler you want to use. Therefore yes, you have to install a compiler yourself.

Comment: Thank you Some programmer dude!! Appreciate your answer. I agree, now is a great time to get in with how accessible information/resources are. Gerhardh, one might think there would be a default compiler in place once you have the extensions downloaded. I didn't have to do this for when I coded scripts in C# for game development nor did I have this issue when I was programming in Java years ago. Though, it is great to learn and know, thanks! Quick replies from you both!!!!

Comment: Thank you again, I went through that link you sent and now my code compiles and runs!